# Sudoku puzzles of different sizes

Tags: data-request, games

Does anyone know where I can download already generated Sudoku puzzles of different sizes, even greater than 16x16?

The format where they are saved it's not important provided I can parse them relatively easily. The size of the dataset should at least be of 100.

Note: I've looked at the software [qqwing](https://qqwing.com/), but it seems to generate only 9x9 grids. Furthermore, it would be nice to have them already generated and, maybe, stored in a file format like `.csv`, so that I don't have to change the code of other people to obtain what I want. Moreover, I'm actually more interested in grids greater than 9x9. Finally, I'm not necessarily looking for the solutions.

Comment: quick googling reveals kaggle and others

Comment: @philshem It doesn't look to be exactly what I'm looking for: from what I've seen it's just a bunch of 9x9 Sudoku puzzles.

Comment: Googling '`N`x`N` sudoku generator github' (with `N` a square number like 25) gives various hobby projects as result, such as https://github.com/sergisiso/Sudoku-CNF-generator

Comment: According to the readme this should do exactly what you want: http://ia.udl.cat/remository/func-startdown/5/